# Passing user input from one Python script to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm

I have written a script that imports existing data from a `.csv` file, modifies it, plots it, and also asks the user for an input (`input2`) that is used as the graph title and filename for the data set and graph. I would like to have another script (`import.py`) that executes the original script (`new_file.py`) and is able to determine what the user's input was so that I can access the newly-created files. How can I pass the user input from one script to the other?

The script that takes the user input is `new_file.py`:

```
def create_graph():
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

    input1 = input("Enter the file you want to import: ")
    data_file = pd.read_excel(input1 + ".xlsx")
    ws = np.array(data_file)

    a = ws[:, 0]
    b = ws[:, 1]
    c = ws[:, 2]
    bc = b + c

    my_data1 = np.vstack((a, b, c, bc))
    my_data1 = my_data1.T

    input2 = input("Enter the name for new graph: ")
    np.savetxt(input2 + ".csv", my_data1, delimiter=',')

    plt.plot(a, b, 'ro')
    plt.plot(a, c, 'go')
    plt.plot(a, bc, 'bo')
    plt.ylabel("y-axis")
    plt.xlabel("x-axis")
    plt.legend(['Column 1 data', 'Column 2 data', 'Column 3 data'], loc='best')
    plt.title(input2)
    plt.savefig(input2)
    plt.show()
```

The second script (`import.py`) that I am trying to use to run this is currently:

```
import new_file as nf

nf.create_graph()
```

I'm not sure how to pass `input2` from `new_file.py` to `import.py`. Can anyone help me please? Thank you

Comment: Have you tried running this? I'm not sure what the problem is. It should work fine since you define input2 within your function that is being called.

Comment: Just return the value(s) from the function. https://www.learnpython.org/en/Functions

Answer (score 1):

Simply return the value.

```
def create_graph():
    ...
    return input2
```

then in your other script:

```
import new_file as nf

input2 = nf.create_graph()
```

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Very new to this. I appreciate everyone's time and responses

Answer (score 1):

It looks like what you're wanting to do it return information from your function.

```
def create_graph():
    # ... all of your code other code ...
    return input2
```

Then inside of your import.py you can receive your returned value like this:

```
import new_file as nf

input2 = nf.create_graph()
# use input2 however you want
```